# How to call a common function effectively whether synchronous or asynchronous function is executed using Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to call a common function whether **synchronous** function is invoked or **asynchronous** function is invoked.

This is how I first wrote but this is not correct as `foo` will be called before asynchronous function is completed.

```
function main(element) {
  if (element.id === 'sync') {
    syncFunction();
  } else {
    asyncFunction();
  }
  foo();
}
```

So, I came up with this but here I feel like I am repeating the call to `foo` too many times. Is there a better way?

```
function main(element) {
  if (element.id === 'sync') {
    syncFunction();
    foo();
  } else {
    asyncFunction().then(() => {
      foo();
    });
  }
}
```

I could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and refactor this even better but where this code eventually will run [doesn't support it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_limitations.htm). Is there a way to better write this using promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the result of the call into a `Promise.resolve()`, you can chain `.then` onto it unconditionally.

```
function main(element) {
    Promise.resolve((element.id === 'sync' ? syncFunction : asyncFunction)())
        .then(foo);
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Not sure if I am doing something wrong but when I try this `foo` is not executed after async function. Here is the jsfiddle I am using : https://jsfiddle.net/q5ne19rf/49/

Comment: You forgot to call `resolve` in `asyncFunction`, so the Promise hangs